# function field of projective plane isomorphic to function field of product of projective line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I need to show that given a projective plane $P^{2}$ and product of  projective line $P^{1}\times P^{1}$,their function field are isomorphic. However, what is the proper definition of function field $k(P^{1}\times P^{1})$? Since it cannot be direct product of $k(P^{1})\times k(P^{1})$. Should it be direct sum of fields?
And how are they isomorphic to each other?

Comment: Lying inside $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$ there's $\mathbb{A}^1\times \mathbb{A}^1$ a.k.a $\mathbb{A}^2$ that lies inside $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: Also a product or two fields (or a direct sum, this is the same) shall never be integral, let alone a field.